# Jquery autocomplete, stop focus when item is selected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I using to jquery autocomplete. Input focus continues when i search and select. I want no "focus" when I make a selection. So when i search and select veriseti_ismi_1 stop focus on input. How can i do this for my code?

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Veriseti_ismi_1",
    "Veriseti_ismi_2",
    "Veriseti_ismi_3",
    "Veriseti_ismi_4"
  ];

  var $elem = $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    }),
    elemAutocomplete = $elem.data("ui-autocomplete") || $elem.data("autocomplete");
  if (elemAutocomplete) {
    elemAutocomplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      var newText = String(item.value).replace(
        new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
        "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");

      return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div>" + newText + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
  }

});

$('#tags').on('focusout', function(e) {
  let curElem = this;
  $('.ui-menu-item').each(function() {
    if ($(curElem).val() == $(this).text())
      $(this).hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="tags" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [select](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) function of `autoComplete` to trigger something on selection of your searched text.

In addition, you can also handle `event` like getting the `data` you `selected` from your tags `input` as well you can `ajax` calls and other necessary things needed on your `select` function as well.

Lastly, to `focusout` from the input you need to use [blur()](https://api.jquery.com/blur/) function of `jQuery`.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Veriseti_ismi_1",
    "Veriseti_ismi_2",
    "Veriseti_ismi_3",
    "Veriseti_ismi_4"
  ];

  var $elem = $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      select: function(x, i) { //select function
        $("#tags").blur(); //focus out
       //do other stuff
      },
    }),
    elemAutocomplete = $elem.data("ui-autocomplete") || $elem.data("autocomplete");
  if (elemAutocomplete) {
    elemAutocomplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      var newText = String(item.value).replace(
        new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
        "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");

      return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div>" + newText + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
  }


});


$('#tags').on('focusout', function(e) {
  let curElem = this;
  $('.ui-menu-item').each(function() {
    if ($(curElem).val() == $(this).text())
      $(this).hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="tags" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `select` option to `autocomplete` init which is a function and inside that, can call `blur` event of `input`:

```js
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
    "Veriseti_ismi_1",
    "Veriseti_ismi_2",
    "Veriseti_ismi_3",
    "Veriseti_ismi_4"
  ];

  var $elem = $("#tags").autocomplete({
      source: availableTags,
      
      // NEW CODE
      select: function( event, ui ) {
       $("#tags").blur()
      }
      // END OD NEW CODE
    }),
    elemAutocomplete = $elem.data("ui-autocomplete") || $elem.data("autocomplete");
  if (elemAutocomplete) {
    elemAutocomplete._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
      var newText = String(item.value).replace(
        new RegExp(this.term, "gi"),
        "<span class='ui-state-highlight'>$&</span>");

      return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.autocomplete", item)
        .append("<div>" + newText + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
  }

});

$('#tags').on('focusout', function(e) {
  let curElem = this;
  
  // To see it works
  
  console.log('blurred')
  $('.ui-menu-item').each(function() {
    if ($(curElem).val() == $(this).text())
      $(this).hide()
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input id="tags" type="text" />
```